# PHP parsing of text

Tags: php

I have some PHP code which automates some process. Sometimes there is an error and I would like to get more data and save it for later review.

So what I am looking for is to check if there is an error and then extract the info

```
 <tr id="part1AModel.errors">
                 <td colspan="5">  
                    <h3><font color="red">Validation Error</font></h3>You must correct the following error(s) before proceeding:
                    <ul>

                            <li><font color="red">The requested effective date entered is not an expedited date.<br/></font> </li>

                    </ul>  
                    For assistance, please contact the Help Desk.<hr> 
                 </td></tr>
```

I  check with `strpos($input,"part1AModel.errors") > -1` if there is an error

but how can I get

`Validation Error`

and

`The requested effective date entered is not an expedited date.` ?

We know they are both inside  (font color="red")

Comment: What about using PHP: DOM? http://php.net/manual/es/book.dom.php

Comment: How would i go about to get all inner text inside of the <font color="red"> elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. With regex (considering that you don't want some more complex html parsing).

```
preg_match_all('/<font color=\"red\">(.*?)<\/font>/', $html, $matches);
```

The `$html` variable should contain the html content you just posted. The result will be saved in `$matches`.